# What is going wrong with my multidimentional array function?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

here I have a problem. I want to manipulate the following Matrix

Matrix A =
1---------2----------3

4---------5----------6

7---------8----------9

into

7---------8----------9

4---------5----------6

1---------2----------3

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void f(int ArrayName, int Size);
int main()
{

    int x[3][3]={{1,2,3}, {4, 5,6},{7,8,9}};

    f(x, 3);

    system("pause");

}

void f(int ArrayName, int Size)
{
     int holder;
     for(int i=0; i<Size; i++){
             for(int j=0; j<Size; j++)
             {
                     holder=ArrayName[i][j];
                     ArrayName[i][j]=ArrayName[i+2][j+2];
                     ArrayName[i+2][j+2]=holder;
             }
             }


     for(int k=0; k<Size; k++)
             for(int l=0; l<Size; l++)
             {
                  cout<<ArrayName[k][l];  
                  if(l=3) cout<<"\n";
             }

}



Errors:
 E:\Semester 2\CPrograms\Array2.cpp In function `int main()':
10 E:\Semester 2\CPrograms\Array2.cpp invalid conversion from `int (*)[3][3]' to `int'
10 E:\Semester 2\CPrograms\Array2.cpp   initializing argument 1 of `void f(int, int)'
 E:\Semester 2\CPrograms\Array2.cpp In function `void f(int, int)':
22 E:\Semester 2\CPrograms\Array2.cpp invalid types `int[int]' for array subscript
(Last error repeated for five times)
```

Comment: Your function `f` should have the signature `void f(int** ArrayName, int Size);`

Comment: Also know that you are about to write out of bounds `ArrayName[i+2][j+2]=holder`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All is done before us.:)

You can do quickly the assignment using standard algorithm `std::reverse` declared in header `<algorithm>`

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    int a[3][3] =
    {
        { 1, 2, 3 }, 
        { 4, 5, 6 },
        { 7, 8, 9 }
    };

    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::reverse( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ) );

    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 

7 8 9 
4 5 6 
1 2 3
```

As for your code then already this function declaration

```
void f(int ArrayName, int Size);
```

is wrong.

The first parameter should be either a reference to the array or a pointer to its first element.

For example

```
void f( int ( &ArrayName )[3][3] );
```

or

```
void f( int ( *ArrayName )[3], int Size );
```

If you want to write the function yourself then it can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>

void reverse( int ( *ArrayName )[3], size_t Size )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < Size / 2; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
        {
            int tmp = ArrayName[i][j];
            ArrayName[i][j] = ArrayName[Size - i - 1][j];
            ArrayName[Size - i - 1][j] = tmp;
        }
    }
}

int main() 
{
    int a[3][3] =
    {
        { 1, 2, 3 }, 
        { 4, 5, 6 },
        { 7, 8, 9 }
    };

    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    ::reverse( a, 3 );

    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output will be the same as above.

Answer (score 2):

The prototype and declaration of your function should be :

```
void f(int ArrayName[][3], int Size)
```

Modify the code as:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void f(int ArrayName[][3], int Size);   //change here
int main()
{

int x[3][3]={{1,2,3}, {4, 5,6},{7,8,9}};

f(x, 3);

system("pause");

}

void f(int ArrayName[][3], int Size)   //change here
 {
 int holder;
 for(int i=0; i<Size/2; i++){            //change here
         for(int j=0; j<Size; j++)
         {
                 holder=ArrayName[i][j];
                 ArrayName[i][j]=ArrayName[size-i-1][size-i-1]; //change here
                 ArrayName[size-i-1][size-i-1]=holder;     //change here
         }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution in the code below. It uses the matrix as a vector, but has no dimension dependencies in the `f()` function prototype.

You have some errors in your code:

- The array `x[][]` has to be passed by reference/pointer and not by value, then the function `f()` has to receive a pointer (or a reference) to int and not an int!
- The for-loop scanning the matrix rows doesn't have to be `for(int i=0; i<Size; i++)`, but  `for(int i=0; i<Size/2; i++)`. Using `i<Size` you swaps two times all the rows and then it seems nothing happens!
- The following code:

> ```
> ArrayName[i][j]=ArrayName[i+2][j+2];
> ArrayName[i+2][j+2]=holder;
> ```

should be:

> ```
> ArrayName[i][j]=ArrayName[Size-i-1][j];
> ArrayName[Size-i-1][j]=holder;
> ```

- The following code:

> ```
> if(l=3) cout<<"\n";
> ```

l=3 assigns a value, don't do a comparison.

It should be:

> ```
> if(l==Size-1) cout<<"\n";
> ```

---

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
void f(int * ArrayName, int Size);

int main()
{
    static const int Size=4;
    int x[Size][Size];

    //Loads the numbes into the matrix
    for(int i=0;i<Size;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<Size;j++)
            x[i][j]=i*Size+j+1;

    f(&x[0][0], Size);
}

void f(int *ArrayName, int Size)
{
    int holder;
    cout << "Input\n";
    for(int k=0; k<Size; k++) {
        for(int l=0; l<Size; l++)             
            cout<<ArrayName[k*Size+l]<<" ";  
        cout << "\n";
    }

    // Elaborate the matrix
    // ----------------------------------------
    for(int i=0; i<Size / 2; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<Size; j++) {
            holder=ArrayName[i*Size+j];
            ArrayName[i*Size+j]=ArrayName[(Size-i-1)*Size+j];
            ArrayName[(Size-i-1)*Size+j]=holder;
        }
    }
    // ----------------------------------------

    cout << "----------\n" << "Output\n";

    for(int k=0; k<Size; k++) {
        for(int l=0; l<Size; l++)             
            cout<<ArrayName[k*Size+l]<<" ";  
        cout << "\n";
    }

}
```